# Model and Link error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement Paypal into an application of mine. I have gone through the excellent railscasts demo at http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics

However I dont really have a cart in my app, its more of a one off purchase. But I want to get Paypal intergrated and not just have a "button".

I took the Cart model from the demo and built my own:

```
class Paypal < ActiveRecord::Base
  def paypal_url
        values = {
          :business => 'seller_1229899173_biz@railscasts.com',
          :cmd => '_cart',
          :upload => 1,
          :return => return_url,
          :invoice => id
        }
       "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end
end
```

Then for a link in my view I have:

```
<%= link_to "Checkout", @paypal.paypal_url(products_url) %>
```

I know this is not right, as I dont have any products as such. But I would like to pass varilables to payal and recieve variabled back. At the moment I get the error:

```
undefined method `paypal_url' for nil:NilClass
```

Which happens on load.

In my routes I have included:

```
 resources :paypal
```

But no joy!

Comment: class Paypal << ActiveRecord::Base
or 
class Paypal < ActiveRecord::Base
?

Comment: The problem resides where you're *calling* `paypal_url`, so post that code.

Comment: sorry, i am having a nightmare today, its now in the post :)

Comment: is there anything else i can add?

Comment: do you have @paypal=Paypal.new in your controller action code?